# ioredis using pipeline to delete keys

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to use ioredis (nodejs) to delete multiple keys with the `pipeline` method.

But it has no impact on my keys in redis-cli.

My code:

```js
    const Redis = require('ioredis')
    const redis = new Redis()
    redis.scanStream({ match: 'myprefix:*' })
        .on('data', async(keys) => {
            if (keys.length) {
                const pipeline = this.store.pipeline()
                keys.forEach((key) => {
                  pipeline.del(key)
                })
                await pipeline.exec((err, results) => {
                  console.log(results) // returns [ [ null, 0 ], [ null, 0 ], [ null, 0 ], [ null, 0 ], [ null, 0 ] ]
                  console.log(err) // returns null
                })
            }
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log("end") // returns "end"
        }
```

I also tested the following code: which does nothing either:

```js
    ...
    const pipeline = this.store.pipeline()
    await pipeline.del('anotherprefix:test')
    await pipeline.exec((err, results) => {
        console.log(results) // returns [ [ null, 0 ] ]
        console.log(err) // returns null
    })
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the prefix from the deletion request.

And then do for example:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const redis = new Redis()
const prefix = 'myprefix'

redis.scanStream({ match: prefix +':*' })
    .on('data', async(keys) => {
        if (keys.length) {
            const pipeline = this.store.pipeline()
            keys.forEach((key) => {
              pipeline.del(key.replace(prefix + ':', '')
            })
            await pipeline.exec()
        }
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        ...
    }
```